# Service Stack and NHibernate

Tags: servicestack

I am following this example: [Using NHibernate with ServiceStack](http://www.philliphaydon.com/2012/06/using-nhibernate-with-servicestack)

In the Contacts class library is there way to not have to create another Product class since we already have the Model or is this required? Seems like dependency injection could be used here.

Also could I move the model and mappings into thier own class library outside of the Services project?

How would I return model that had a property that was another model? I.e. Say we had an employee model that was linked to a person model by Id and the person model contained the employee Date Of Birth, I am not seeing how I would return that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create seperate models (or DTOs), however, I think when dealing with different ORMs the custom DTOs will make life easier. You can easily translate the properties with ServiceStack's property translater or something like AutoMapper.

I would create your DTOs in the manner that you want others to consume them. In other words you DTO's don't need to align with the underlying tables. You can combine models and flatten the data into useful DTOs. In your example the Employee class could expose the date of birth and any other person properties.

You can easily keep your DTOs in a separate project. I have done this in projects where I wanted to re-use the DTO classes elsewhere without including the services.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am planning to have DTO's in thier own assembly and Models/Mappings in another separate assembly both separate from the service assembly.